# Shortest Calculator program in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to python programming. I have gone through many python calculator codes online and was wondering if there is a way to include as many python inbuilt arithmetic operations as possible without any external libraries with the code as short as possible.

Needed for a small implementation in my project. Thanks!!!

eg.

```
Input: 5 / 2
output: 2.5
Input: 5 // 2
output: 2
Input: 5 ** 2
Output: 25
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the shortest and worst possible python calculator code I can think of:

```
def worst_calculator_ever(input):
    return eval(input)
```

NOTE: your input should always be a string

Answer (score 0):

You can make a calculator in one line of python.

```
print(eval(input()));
```